# Latex template - compilation

Tags: latex

I downloaded this LaTex template: https://www.latextemplates.com/template/plasmati-graduate-cv . When I want to compile there is an error 
Translation: 'File with record not found.' Or 'Log file not found.'

[image]

What to do with that please?

```
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or(fontspec) LuaTeX.(fontspec)(fontspec) You must change your typesetting engine to,(fontspec) e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of(fontspec) "latex" or "pdflatex".For immediate help type H <return>.... \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58043/texmaker-error-file-not-found
Does this resolve your question?

Comment: No, now there is an error I added to my question.

Comment: You need to compile with xelatex or lualatex instead of pdflatex. Instead of `quick build` choose one of them for from the drop down menu for compiling your document

Answer (score 0):

Download xetex here https://ctan.org/pkg/xetex?lang=en following links and instructions or by your package repository.

Comment: Thank you and where is Download? I don't see it.

Comment: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html here or https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html Look for yourself please.